# Adding Selection Property to ListboxVBA

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I'm trying to populate a Listbox from a Worksheet, and would like to predetermine which list items already have a Check Box. I've found ways to determine which items in a listbox are checked, but no the other way around. I have the code to run through my list and insert each item within my range, but cannot find a way to assign the selected property. My worksheet will have each item to add and a 1 or 0 as to whether its selected.

Worksheet;

```
    Item   Include?

    TaskA   1 
    TaskB   0 
    TaskC   1
```

I would like to have a selected mark next to everything with a 1, and not include one for everything with a 0.

Here's my current attempt where I attempt a loop(i) that looks up in the table next to the field it inserts:

```
For Each RngTask In ws.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Count, 2))
    FRM_StorageOptions.StorageList.AddItem RngTask.Value
    If ws.Cells(i, 2) = 1 Then
        FRM_StorageOptions.StorageList.Selected(i - 1) = True
    Else
        FRM_StorageOptions.StorageList.Selected(i - 1) = False
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next RngTask
```

However it wont allow me to assign this property and returns "Could not set the selected property. Invalid Property value ". Adding to the list works fine without my attempt to add the selected value.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the ListBox on a UserForm, or on the worksheet itself?

Comment: The listbox is on a userform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ws.Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Count, 2))` will fail if `ws <> ActiveSheet`.  That is because the cells inside a range have to be be qualified to the same worksheet as the range.

It appears that you want to add values from column A and check column B to see if they should be selected.  You could is adding from column B and checking column B.

```
    Item    Include?
    TaskA         1 
    TaskB         0 
    TaskC         1
```

### Here is my best guess to what you what to accomplish.

```
With FRM_StorageOptions.StorageList
    For Each RngTask In ws.Range("A2", "A" & Count)

        .AddItem RngTask.Value

        .Selected(.ListCount - 1) = RngTask.Offset(0, 1) = 1

    Next RngTask
End With
```

Comment: That ended up just adding all the items, with none of them selected. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: I think that you might have the settings wrong for the listbox.  Here is my test stub [Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5yl69y0eho0p7in/test-select-list.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot! Follow up question, what setting can I change so it doesn't highlight the entire list item, but just checks the box next to it.

Comment: I'm happy that I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

`Set` is used to assign objects. When you want to assign a non-object value like a Boolean or an Integer, you don't use `Set`

Try changing:

```
Set FRM_StorageOptions.StorageList.Selected(i - 1) = True
```

to:

```
FRM_StorageOptions.StorageList.Selected(i - 1) = True
```

and do the same for the other two lines that use `Set`

Even though the Listbox itself is an object, the properties you are assigning are not objects and thus `Set` is not used

Comment: OK, I think I should have known that one. However, now I get "Could not set the Selected Property. Invalid Property value".

Comment: @colinsinclair - Do you have MultiSelect set to true?